# Font choice of Android Enthusiasts is rendered dreadfully in Chrome on Windows

Tags: discussion

Here is a screenshot from a topic on this QA site:

[image]

As you can see, it's pretty hard to read.

I am using Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10

Here is a screenshot from the listing:

[image]

Comment: I had this happen on mathematica.stackexchange.com once not sure why.  It was fixed with in a day not sure by whom.

Comment: I'm honestly curious why some are facing this issue, and the rest aren't (I don't have this issue). I remember last time there was an issue with DirectWrite on Chrome, but since then the flag option has been removed from Chrome. The next thing is, is it because of ClearType? Installed Roboto font..?